# How to Launch an Application exe file OnEnd event in install shield script

Tags: installshield

I have a question regarding "InstallShield" DevStudio 9.

I want to Launch an Application exe file from a particular location at the OnEnd event in install shield script.

can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

LaunchAppAndWait( szProgram, szCmdLine, nOptions );